# Pandas Dynamically Remove Row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data set which contains account_number, date, balance, interest charged, and code. This is accounting data so transactions are posted and then reversed if they're was a mistake by the data provider so things can be posted and reversed multiple times.

```
Account_Number   Date        Balance    Interest Charged   Code
0012            01/01/2017   1,000,000     $ 50.00          Posted
0012            01/05/2017   1,000,000     $-50.00          Reversed 
0012            01/07/2017   1,000,000     $ 50.00          Posted
0012            01/10/2017   1,000,000     $-50.00          Reversed
0012            01/15/2017   1,000,000     $50.00           Posted
0012            01/17/2017   1,500,000     $25.00           Posted
0012            01/18/2017   1,500,000     $-25.00          Reversed
```

Looking at the data set above- I am trying to figure out a way to look at every row by account number and balance and if they're is a inverse charge it should remove both of those rows and only keep a charge if they're is no corresponding reversal for it (01/15/2017). For example on 01/01/2017 a charge of 50.00 dollar was posted on a balance of 1,000,000 and on 01/05/2017 the charged was reversed on the same balance -- so both of these rows should be thrown out. This is the same case for 01/07 and 01/10.

I am not to sure on how to code out this problem - any ideas or tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with a question like this is that there are many corner cases. Optimizing for them many or many not depend on how the data is already processed. That being said, here is one solution. Assuming -

For each Account number and balance, the for for each Reversed transaction is just after the corresponding payment.

```
>>import pandas as pd
>>from datetime import date
>>df = pd.DataFrame(data = [
                    ['0012', date(2017, 1, 1), 1000000, 50, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 5), 1000000, -50, 'Reversed'],
                    ['0012', date(2017, 1, 7), 1000000, 50, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 10), 1000000, -50, 'Reversed'], 
                    ['0012', date(2017, 1, 15), 1000000, 50, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 17), 1500000, 25, 'Posted'],
                    ['0012', date(2017, 1, 18), 1500000, -25, 'Reversed'],],
        columns=['Account_Number', 'Date', 'Balance', 'Interest Charged', 'Code'])
>>df
  Account_Number        Date  Balance  Interest Charged      Code
0           0012  2017-01-01  1000000                50    Posted
1           0012  2017-01-05  1000000               -50  Reversed
2           0012  2017-01-07  1000000                50    Posted
3           0012  2017-01-10  1000000               -50  Reversed
4           0012  2017-01-15  1000000                50    Posted
5           0012  2017-01-17  1500000                25    Posted
6           0012  2017-01-18  1500000               -25  Reversed

>> def f(df_g):
    idx = df_g[df_g['Code'] == 'Reversed'].index
    return df_g.loc[~df_g.index.isin(idx.union(idx-1)), ['Date', 'Interest Charged', 'Code']]

>>df.groupby(['Account_Number', 'Balance']).apply(f).reset_index().loc[:, df.columns]
   Account_Number        Date  Balance  Interest Charged    Code
0           0012  2017-01-15  1000000                50  Posted
```

How it works - Basically for each combination of Account Number and Balance, I look at the Rows with Reversed, and I remove them plus the row just before it.

EDIT: - To make it slightly more Robust (now it picked up the last row based on Amount, Balance and account_number:

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame(data = [
                ['0012', date(2017, 1, 1), 1000000, 53, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 7), 1000000, 50, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 5), 1000000, -50, 'Reversed'],
                ['0012', date(2017, 1, 10), 1000000, -53, 'Reversed'], 
                ['0012', date(2017, 1, 15), 1000000, 50, 'Posted'],['0012', date(2017, 1, 17), 1500000, 25, 'Posted'],
                ['0012', date(2017, 1, 18), 1500000, -25, 'Reversed'],],
    columns=['Account_Number', 'Date', 'Balance', 'Interest Charged', 'Code'])
>>df
  Account_Number        Date  Balance  Interest Charged      Code
0           0012  2017-01-01  1000000                53    Posted
1           0012  2017-01-07  1000000                50    Posted
2           0012  2017-01-05  1000000               -50  Reversed
3           0012  2017-01-10  1000000               -53  Reversed
4           0012  2017-01-15  1000000                50    Posted
5           0012  2017-01-17  1500000                25    Posted
6           0012  2017-01-18  1500000               -25  Reversed

>>output_cols = df.columns
>>df['ABS_VALUE'] = df['Interest Charged'].abs()

>>def f(df_g):
    df_g = df_g.reset_index() # Added this new line
    idx = df_g[df_g['Code'] == 'Reversed'].index
    return df_g.loc[~df_g.index.isin(idx.union(idx-1)), ['Date', 'Interest Charged', 'Code']]

>>df.groupby(['Account_Number', 'Balance', 'ABS_VALUE']).apply(f).reset_index().loc[:, output_cols]
  Account_Number        Date  Balance  Interest Charged    Code
0           0012  2017-01-15  1000000                50  Posted
```

Comment: Hmm.. what if the row is not right before it ? For example -- what if the posted transaction is in row 1 and the reversed transaction is in row 5?

Comment: @JasGoraya unless you've got a specific (unique) transaction ID that a pair of transactions has then you've got no real way of relating two records together.

Comment: Your correct -- this is a best effort attempt to match corresponding transactions based on values in a column (Balance and Interest charged) I have other columns I can evaluate in my data frame but left them out of the example for the sake of simplicity. I am not aiming for 100% percent accuracy -- in most cases its pretty obvious which transactions are being posted and then reversed,

Comment: Made the changes

Comment: Thanks Sahil - I am testing the code out to see if I can replicate/implement on my data set. What is the purpose of this line of code return df_g.loc[~df_g.index.isin(idx.union(idx-1)), ['Date', 'Interest Charged', 'Code']] ?

Comment: `df_g.index.isin(idx.union(idx-1)` takes the union of rows Identified by `idx` and and adds the rows that that are one line before. the `~` is like the NOT, so we are now excluding all these rows. Finally `['Date', 'Interest Charged', 'Code']` is just the column selection